# RequestParam with special character '+'

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, special-characters

in my Controller I have the requestMapping "searchUser" with 4 request parameters.
For the request parameter "phoneNumber" I also accept special characters like '(' , ')', '-' and '+'.

Expect of the character '+' all characters are shown in my log. If I send for example the values like "+123" or "123+1" I get i my controller " 123" and "123 1"
It replaces the "+" with a space.

It only happens with '+'

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search", produces = "application/json")
    public List<User> getWebUserProfiles(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName,
        @RequestParam("email") String email
        @RequestParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber);
```

Do you know what I have to add?

thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I using Angular 2 for my frontend where I have a form and I send the values further to my spring-boot backend. 
My http-service in angular:

```
   search(searchParams: any){
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('firstName', searchParams.firstName);
        params.set('lastName', searchParams.lastName);
        params.set('email', searchParams.email);
        params.set('phoneNumber', searchParams.phoneNumber);

        return this._http.get(this.baseURL+'search', 
                        { search:params })
                        .map(response => response.json())
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: That's because ``+`` is a special character in a URL. Try to send it to your webserver as ``%2C``.

Comment: This is normal.  See the [Form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) section of the HTML specification.  How are you invoking the URL?  If it’s called from an HTML form in a browser, the `+` should be percent-escaped automatically.

Comment: @f1sh - %2C is a comma, %2B is the plus. And to add more to your comment, plus is treated as an URL escape for spaces. One of few ways to do it. trap look into URL Encoding some more.

Comment: @Quintium you are correct. It's apparently very hard to read an ascii table :D

Comment: @VGR . I invoking it in my angular frontend. please see UPDATE

Answer (score 6):

Ok I solved it.

I encoded it in my fronted. There were no other options.

params.set('phoneNumber', encodeURIComponent(searchParams.phoneNumber));

Thank you to for your help!

Comment: You should ensure that your front end URI-encodes *all* fields. Either by coding it individually, or by ensuring that your framework takes care of it. Otherwise the user will get surprises e.g. if they put an `&` into a text field.

Comment: It doesn't look right. The https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html says it is already doing encoding by default. So, apparently something else is doing something wrong - could be a server side decoding it twice or something. Try to see raw traffic and find out where do you have "+" or " ".

Comment: @slim Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @kan Really? In my case it actually does not do it. In my spring-boot backend I encode everthing  and give it to the next controller. I also tried to set the content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. But it does not work

Comment: I bet spring-boot does all encoding/decoding magic behind the scenes already. What exactly are you encoding in spring-boot and why?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace any instance of '+' with '%2B' on the javascript end before sending it to server.

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57991436/9103231)